# Integration or build instructions for libjpeg-turbo on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jpeg, libjpeg-turbo

Various pages can be found on the internet mentioning libjpeg-turbo for Android ([example](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.linaro.devel/6967)). They all point at the repository [here](http://git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=people/tomgall/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo.git;a=summary), and say to read `ANDROID.txt` for build instructions. There's no such text file in the repository though. Is this repository the official place to go to get libjpeg-turbo for Android? If so, where are the build/integration instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, the file's in a branch in that repository.

Also found this info:

https://wiki.linaro.org/BenjaminGaignard/libjpeg-turboAndSkia

Answer (score 9):

I ported libjpeg-turbo for use in android a number of months back.

You can find the code here:

http://git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=people/tomgall/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/android

Android.txt is there etc.  Just moved out the external/jpeg directory and replace with this named exactly the same external/jpeg, it'll build and run fine.

Plan to push this into ASOP fairly soon. (I know cyanogenmod is also considering it currently)

Comment: Is there any instructions on including this into an app via NDK?

Answer (score 0):

Use Makefile.am file to see what files you need to compile and write that in your own Android.mk makefile.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that's not really an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260149/libjpeg-turbo-for-android) question and answers which seem pretty detailed on answering this. Actually trying it out right now as my use case is to embed this into an application and not recompile Android to use this instead of the built-in `libjpeg`.

Comment: My only gotcha was that building it with ndk `r8d` was giving me trouble, so upgrading to `r10d` fixed it.