# libjpeg-turbo in android app not using SIMD

Tags: android-ndk, simd, libjpeg-turbo

I successfully compiled libjpeg-turbo libraries in my android app following the recipe here: [libjpeg-turbo for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260149/libjpeg-turbo-for-android).

Trying to assess the performance improvement of NEON SIMD instructions in the library, I tried to enable/disable NEON support. Interestingly, no differences.

Digging through the code, looks like `init_simd()` in `jsimd_arm.c` is never executed at runtime.

This function is called by `libjpeg_arch_specific_init()` which is called when the library is first loaded.

I believe the glitch originates from this library being static as opposed to dynamic, hence never "loaded" (see comment from DRC at end of this thread: http://sourceforge.net/p/libjpeg-turbo/patches/26/)

Does it make sense? Anyone else seen this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I also don't see much difference on performance improvement.

Comment: I dont see much perf. improvement too. I am attaching it statically. Did you guys figure out a rootcause for this issue?