# How to optimize a native code with android-ndk (Speed Optimization)

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, android-ndk, clang

I'm compiling a native code using cygwin and Windows7.
I got many optimization tips on Internet.

```
APP_OPTIM := release
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=0
-DNDEBUG
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O2
```

But I can't understand exactly how to set these on Application.mk and Android.mk.
I tried many cases by applying the above tips.
but, I don't think that the optimization is applied in my native code.

Application.mk

```
APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(shell pwd)
APP_MODULES := native_lib
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := crypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libcrypto.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := native_lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nativeC.c \
                   AES/main.c \
                   AES/aes.c \  

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ./lib                  
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := crypto
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O2
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -march=armv6 -marm -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I hope many comments.

---

**In Addition,**

First, I tried to compare the cases between with the above flag and without it. (e.g. I compiled my program with APP_OPTIM := release in Application.mk, and then I compiled without it or with APP_OPTIM := debug, again.) But, I cannot see any change of the running speed.

Second, this is the most important, My program compare the speed of two modules. (For convenience, I call them module A, B) Module A is prebuilt (which is libcrypto.so in Android.mk). And I want to apply optimization into Module B. First of all, I compared the speed test of module A and B in PC (Visual Studio 2010). When I tried module A and B in the PC, the module B is faster than A. (Of course, I precompiled the module A and I use it by calling the library.) Now I'm porting the my program for PC into it for Android. But in Android, the module B is too slower than A.

Therefore, I concluded that this is not optimized.

In summary,

1. I compared the speed between with the flag and without it.
2. When running this program in PC, the precompiled module A is faster than
   B, But in Android, it's totally opposite.

Do you thnk what my program's problem is ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How can you tell your compiled code isn't optimized?

Comment: I added the details in the below Answer. (In Addition...)

Comment: you can edit your question with more details, you shouldn't make an answer that isn't actually an answer.

Comment: Your PC is an `Intel` machine, while phone is an `ARM`. If you didn't write that code, if you don't know the details you can't make a claim like `Therefore, I concluded that this is not optimized.`.

Comment: My PC's CPU is "Intel COre 2 Quad Q6600" , while the phone's CPU is "ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)". If you need other information to solve my problems, I can give you any information.

Comment: optimization doesn't guarantee an increase in speed. As for @auselen 's suggestion - you're comparing two libraries running on different architectures - there might be differences in performance. The pre-complied library you are comparing against might even be compiled with different optimization on each platform. Unless you can control all these variables its not a valid test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**APP_OPTIM := release**

Put the line `APP_OPTIM := release` into your Application.mk file

**ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=0**

Just pass the `NDK_DEBUG=0` as a parameter to `ndk-build` script. You don't need it once you define `APP_OPTIM := release`.

**-DNDEBUG**

This should go into your `LOCAL_CFLAGS`:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
```

**LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O2**

This is not required actually, since the Android NDK already defines `-O2` optimization.

Comment: Anything doesn't affect the speed. Referentially, both Application.mk and Android.mk are put in <project folder>/jni/.