# Android how to use libjpeg-turbo library

Tags: android, android-ndk

i finally managed to build libjpeg-turbo static library thanks to this
[libjpeg-turbo for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260149/libjpeg-turbo-for-android)
now i have a libjpeg.a and a libsimd.a generated by ndk-build

but i have not been able to find any info about what to do next? i'm decode a jpeg from a buffer (from a socket) to a bitmap using the build in BitmapFactory which works fine

```
byte[] jpgBits = new byte[jpgBitsLen];
dis.readFully(jpgBits);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpgBits, 0, jpgBitsLen);
```

how do i replace BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray with libjpeg-turbo?

i encode the stream on my PC using this

```
tjhandle rmfdJpegCompressor = tjInitCompress();
tjCompress2(rmfdJpegCompressor, (unsigned char *)s_rmfdPixels, MFD_WH, 0, MFD_WH, TJPF_BGRX,
            &rmfdBits, &rmfdBitsLen, TJSAMP_420, RMFD_JPEG_QUALITY,
            0);
tjDestroy(rmfdJpegCompressor);
```

which work fine, so i think there must be an android equivalent?

i read this
https://wiki.linaro.org/BenjaminGaignard/libjpeg-turboAndSkia
does this mean the only way to use it is to rebuild android sources so it uses libjpeg-turbo? i read somewhere there is a compatibility api and a native api for libjpeg-turbo and i'm happy to use whatever api is easiest since i don't fancy rebuilding android

i've tried the following:
 under my project root i created folders jni/include and put turbojpeg.h in there
 under my project root i created folders jni/prebuilt and put libjpeg.a in there

in my java code, i put

```
private native int tjInitDecompress();
```

in MainActivity
and in onCreate i add

```
int i = tjInitDecompress();
Log.d("MainActivity", "i="+i);
```

it builds and runs but crashes at tjInitDecompress

in the log it says:
No implementation found for native Lcom/example.jpegtest/MainActivity;.tjInitDecompress ()I

thanks

Answer (score 5):

well, its been a mountain of work but i finally got something working so i want to let anyone who's interested know how i did it.

first i built the hello-jin demo as described here
https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

then i created a new project, copied the jni and changed the names of the c func to match the new package and class name. don't use - and _ in your package name or you will have problems. just a-x0-9 is best.

then i copied all the libjpeg-turbo file and dirs into jni and tested that ndk-build still worked

then i created a jni wrapper for the libjpg funs like this
tjpegini-arm.c

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */
#include <jni.h>
#include "turbojpeg.h"


/*
 * Class:     libjpegturbo_jniapi
 * Method:    tjInitDecompress
 * Signature: ()I
 */
//package com.design2112.fbmslpit
//public class MainActivity
jint JNICALL Java_com_design2112_fbmslpit_MainActivity_tjInitDecompress
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    return (int)tjInitDecompress();
}


/*
 * Class:     libjpegturbo_jniapi
 * Method:    tjDecompressHeader2
 * Signature: (I[BI)I
 */
jint JNICALL Java_com_design2112_fbmslpit_MainActivity_tjDecompressHeader2
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint handle, jbyteArray jpegBuf, jint jpegSize)
{
    jbyte *real_jpegBuf = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, jpegBuf, 0);
    if (!real_jpegBuf) return -1;
    //jsize length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, real_jpegBuf);

    /*for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += inCArray[i];
    }*/

    int width, height, jpegSubsamp;
    int ret =  tjDecompressHeader2((tjhandle)handle,
                (unsigned char *)real_jpegBuf, (unsigned long)jpegSize, &width, &height,
                &jpegSubsamp);
    if(ret!=0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // ok, so pack width and height together
    return width<<16 | height;
}

/*
 * Class:     libjpegturbo_jniapi
 * Method:    tjDecompress2
 * Signature: (I[BI[IIIIII)V
 */
void JNICALL Java_com_design2112_fbmslpit_MainActivity_tjDecompress2
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint handle, jbyteArray jpegBuf, jint jpegSize, jintArray dstBuf,
  jint width, jint pitch, jint height, jint pixelFormat, jint flags)
{
    jbyte *real_jpegBuf = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, jpegBuf, 0);
    if (!real_jpegBuf) return;
    jint *real_dstBuf = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, dstBuf, 0);
    if (!real_dstBuf) return;

    jsize length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jpegBuf);
    tjDecompress2((tjhandle)handle,
                (unsigned char *)real_jpegBuf, (unsigned long)jpegSize, (unsigned char *)real_dstBuf,
                 width, pitch, height, pixelFormat, flags);
}

/*
 * Class:     libjpegturbo_jniapi
 * Method:    tjDestroy
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
void JNICALL Java_com_design2112_fbmslpit_MainActivity_tjDestroy
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint handle)
{
    tjDestroy((tjhandle)handle);
}
```

IMPORTANT, you will have to rename com_design2112_fbmslpit_MainActivity to your package and class for this to work

add tjpegini-arm.c to the Android.mk makefile then run ndk-build in the jni dir

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk obj/local/armeabi/libjpeg.so  LOCAL_ARM_MODE=arm
```

and copy the .so to the right name and place

```
cp obj/local/armeabi/libjpeg.so ../libs/armeabi/libtjpegjni-arm.so
```

then in my MainAvtivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public native int tjInitDecompress();
    public native int tjDecompressHeader2(int handle, byte[] jpegBits, int jpegBitsLen);    
    public native void tjDecompress2(int handle, byte[] jpegBits,
            int jpegBitsLen, int[] outbuffer, int width, int pitch, int height,
            int pixelFormat, int flags);
    public native void tjDestroy(int handle);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        //Get the text file
        File file = new File(sdcard,"/Download/test.jpg");
        int jpegBitsLen = (int) file.length();
        byte[] jpegBits = new byte[jpegBitsLen];
        DataInputStream dis;
        try {
            dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            dis.readFully(jpegBits);
            dis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.loadLibrary("tjpegjni-arm");

        int jpegDec = tjInitDecompress();

        int wh = tjDecompressHeader2(jpegDec, jpegBits, jpegBitsLen);
        int width = wh>>16;
        int height = wh&0x7fff;

        int[] buffer = new int[width*height];
        tjDecompress2(jpegDec, jpegBits, jpegBitsLen, buffer, width, 0/*pitch*/, height, 2 /*TJPF_RGBX*/, 0);

        tjDestroy(jpegDec);

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(buffer, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    }
```

that's basically it. you can display the bmp any way you want.

this too me a shit load of work to figure out having no jni ndk experience at all. if someone finds this usefull, email me a beer.

UPDATE, here's the shocking news, its taking 20ms to decode a 450x450 image.
the built in BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray does it in about the same!

if anyone else tries this and gets different results, please make a note

Comment: first of all, I do applaud to your courage and determination. You really did a big work here. It's a pity though you rushed into this without checking your bearings before. _There is no chance to beat the built-in Jpeg decoder on Android with `libjpeg-turbo`_. Especially - on small images. ***Where this library can matter?*** To create big (10MByte and more) Jpeg images; to manipulate large Jpeg images (e.g. rotate and crop them). Note that many devices have hardware support for Jpeg encode/decode, which is much faster than any NEON optimization. Again, this is significant only for big images.

Comment: oh well, live and learn, at least i know about jni and ndk now

Comment: So @AlexCohn, is this true for compression as well? I'm trying to replace the built-in `Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG)` by `TJCompressor` and my images are indeed pretty small (they are tiles of a larger image of about 40x40). I right now can only compress about 10 full frames worth tiles per second (about 256 tiles for the image I'm trying to process), so about 2560 small compressions, which I was expecting to bring up to around 20-30 fps by using `libjpeg-turbo`. Any suggestions for better performing jpeg compression in Android land if this is not viable?