# How to use mozjpeg library/executables on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo, mozjpeg

I know, probably the best is to go ahead and try to build it by using NDK, but I never used NDK before, so it's going to be hard. Therefore, I think it's better to ask first. Maybe someone already tried building/running [mozjpeg](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) on Android? Is it even possible?

My primary goal is to perform actions that can be done by using `jpegtran` executable (losslessly rotating, cropping, optimizing jpeg files). From Java code.

I've seen instructions to build libjpeg-turbo: [libjpeg-turbo for android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12260149/1418097) — but do they apply to mozjpeg?