# How to compile libjpeg-turbo for Android on OS X?

Tags: android, android-ndk, libjpeg-turbo

I'm trying to build libjpeg-turbo for Android on OS X. Here is the script that I'm using:

```
# Set these variables to suit your needs
NDK_PATH=/Users/***/android_ndk
BUILD_PLATFORM="darwin-x86_64"
TOOLCHAIN_VERSION="4.9"
ANDROID_VERSION="14"

HOST=arm-linux-androideabi
TOOLCHAIN=${NDK_PATH}/toolchains/${HOST}-${TOOLCHAIN_VERSION}/prebuilt/${BUILD_PLATFORM}
SYSROOT=${NDK_PATH}/platforms/android-${ANDROID_VERSION}/arch-arm
ANDROID_INCLUDES="-I${SYSROOT}/usr/include -I${TOOLCHAIN}/include"
ANDROID_CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -fprefetch-loop-arrays \
  -fstrict-aliasing --sysroot=${SYSROOT} "

export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc
export CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}-g++

export CPP=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-cpp
export AR=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-ar
export AS=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-as
export NM=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-nm
export CC=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-gcc
export LD=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-ld
export RANLIB=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-ranlib
export OBJDUMP=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-objdump
export STRIP=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-strip
cd .
sh ./configure --host=${HOST} \
  CFLAGS="${ANDROID_INCLUDES} ${ANDROID_CFLAGS} -O3" \
  CPPFLAGS="${ANDROID_INCLUDES} ${ANDROID_CFLAGS}" \
  LDFLAGS="${ANDROID_CFLAGS}" --with-simd ${1+"$@"}
make
```

And here is the output:

```
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking dependency style of /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... (cached) /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc option to accept ANSI C... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ld used by /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
checking if the linker (/Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /Users/***/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-g++... arm-linux-androideabi-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether arm-linux-androideabi-g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of arm-linux-androideabi-g++... none
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

What might be the cause of it? What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [libjpeg-turbo for android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260149/libjpeg-turbo-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need change CPP from `${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/${HOST}-cpp` to `$CC ${ANDROID_CFLAGS} -E`:

```
export CPP="$CC ${ANDROID_CFLAGS} -E"
```

Comment: That didn't help. I managed to compile it though using this article http://www.devahead.com/blog/2013/04/building-libjpeg-turbo-for-android/. Not sure what the reasons are.